# Increase the font size on Sublime Text 2 status bar?

Tags: configuration, ide, configuration-files, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is it possible to increase the font size on the Sublime Text `status bar`?  I did some searching and didn't find much at all on the subject.  I sometimes miss important information displayed in the `status bar` simply because its so small I don't notice it.

Comment: Related, for Sublime Text 3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54505560/3066295

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know you should modify theme settings for that. Please take a look at this answer (at the bottom of the page) [Customize interface fonts](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8634)

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! Exact instructions (windows using default theme): **1)** Open `C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Theme - Default\Default.sublime-theme` **2)** Locate `"class" : "label_control",` **3)** Add the param `"font.size": X` where X is your preferred numeric font size

Comment: @voodooGQ You can also go to Preferences > Browse Packages To get to the Packages folder.

Answer (score -2):

Try this it will work for sure in Sublime Text 3 .
navigate to Preferences -> Default File Preferences .
Its will open the file in Sublime text itself
look for "font Courier New 10"(for me Line no: 14)

just change the 10 to X size.