# Is there a way to change the font in the status bar Sublime Text 3?

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-12.04, statusbar, sublimetext3

I am searching for a method to change the font of status bar of Sublime Text 3.. Is there a way to do it? I tried changing system fonts (I am on Ubuntu 12.04), searching through Google gave me no hints..

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's only possible to do in the `.sublime-theme` file:

```
// Status bar label
{
    "class": "label_control",
    "parents": [{"class": "status_bar"}],
    "color": [140,140,140],
    "font.size": 11,
    "font.face": "Droid Sans Mono"
},
```

Comment: I upvoted you answer because it is the way to do it. Unfortunately, my theme is installed via Package Control and I cannot edit the theme. Installing from zip fails.. Do you know how to do it in this case?

Comment: Yes, but only if the theme has some font specified,otherwise not. It's not a big deal if you clone it from the repository, actually, this is intended to be this way!

Comment: If you have a custom theme, create a `Package/User/Default.sublime-theme` file.  This file allows you to override anything set in the theme (and mine is quite extensively expanded upon).  I use ST3 as well.

Answer (score 3):

#### If you can't find any `.sublime-theme`, mentioned in [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21781604/3066295):

(To make it explicitly clear:)

- **Override any current theme** by creating a `Default.sublime-theme` file under **`\Data\Packages\User\`**:

  ```
  [Sublime Text 3 Install dir] \Data\Packages\User\Default.sublime-theme
  ```
- In that file, include something like the [mentioned settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21781604/3066295), but

  **must surround with square brackets `'['`, `']'`:**

```js
  [
      // Status bar label
      {
          "class": "label_control",
          "parents": [{"class": "status_bar"}],
          "color": [130, 130, 130],
          "font.size" : 22
      }
  ]
```